# Aggregation binding in XML view

Tags: json, xml, sapui5

I am trying to create a list from a data model which I defined in the *manifest.json* as "companies".

*companies.json:*

```
{
    "companies" : [
        {
            "name" : "Acme Inc.",
            "city": "Belmont",
            "state": "NH",
            "county": "Belknap",
            "revenue" : "123214125.34"  
        },{
            "name" : "Beam Hdg.",
            "city": "Hancock",
            "state": "NH",
            "county": "Belknap",
            "revenue" : "3235235235.23"  
        },{
            "name" : "Carot Ltd.",
            "city": "Cheshire",
            "state": "NH",
            "county": "Sullivan",
            "revenue" : "Not Disclosed"  
        }]
}
```

In the XML view I tried to create the list with like this:

```
<List id="companyList" items="{/companies}">
   <items>
       <ObjectListItem title="{name}" number="{city}" intro="{country}"/>
   </items>
 </List>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work out. The list displays "No Data". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your model has a name you have to use it in the binding declaration:

```
<List id="companyList" items="{companies>/companies}">
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem title="{companies>name}" number="{companies>city}" intro="{companies>country}"/>
    </items>
</List>
```